# tableview with multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have attached my code below.

While executing I am getting only one section as output but it should return 3 sections in table view. I don't know what I should do.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var itemsInSections: Array<Array<String>> = [["1A", "1B", "1C"], ["2A", "2B"], ["3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E"]]
    var sections: Array<String> = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.itemsInSections[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.sections[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let text = self.itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel!.text = text

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong method

**Replace Old Swift Syntax**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}
```

**With New Swift Syntax**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}
```

Comment: Yes i agree with this.

You are using the old swift syntax for the numberOfSections method